# Error deploying Next.js app to Vercel - TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I'm currently trying to deploy my Next.js application to Vercel, but I'm encountering an error even though it's fine in development. I haven't been able to find anything that would cause this issue.

When attempting to deploy my Next.js app, I'm running into the following error:

> Error occurred prerendering page "/create". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
> TypeError: undefined is not a function, 
> at Array.every ()
> at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/423.js:1:16000
> at Array.filter ()
> at /vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/423.js:1:15704
> at Object.rQ [as useMemo] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:31005)
> at t.useMemo (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:59:7338)
> at de (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/423.js:1:15626)
> at /vercel/path0/.next/server/app/(main)/(routes)/create/page.js:1:5887
> at nh (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:48668)
> at ny (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:27:52524)

this is my create page

```
import { Separator } from '@/components/ui/separator';
import Heading from '@/components/heading';
import CreateForm from '@/components/create-form';

const CreatePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <Heading title="Create Post" subtitle="Make great article!" />
      </div>
      <Separator className="my-4" />
      <CreateForm />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreatePage;
```

and this is my CreateForm component

```
'use client';

import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as z from 'zod';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

import { useEdgeStore } from '@/lib/edgestore';
import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';
import { useMutation } from 'convex/react';
import { api } from '@/convex/_generated/api';

import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { RadioGroup, RadioGroupItem } from '@/components/ui/radio-group';
import Editor from '@/components/editor';
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
} from '@/components/ui/card';
import { SingleImageDropzone } from '@/components/single-image-dropzone';
import { Label } from '@/components/ui/label';

const formSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().min(6, {
    message: 'title must be at least 6 characters.',
  }),
  content: z.string().min(10, {
    message: 'content must be at least 10 characters.',
  }),
  isPublished: z.enum(['published', 'archived']),
});

const CreateForm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File>();
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

  const create = useMutation(api.news.createNews);
  const { edgestore } = useEdgeStore();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      title: '',
      content: '',
    },
  });

  const onChange = async (file?: File) => {
    if (file) {
      setFile(file);
      const res = await edgestore.publicFiles.upload({ file });
      setUrl(res.url);
    }
  };

  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    await create({
      ...values,
      imageUrl: url,
    });

    toast.success('Success');

    setIsSubmitting(false);
    form.reset();
    router.push('/blog');
  }
  return (
    <div className={cn('grid gap-6')}>
      <Card className="w-full mx-auto">
        <CardContent>
          <Form {...form}>
            <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-10">
              <div className="grid gap-2">
                <div className="grid gap-1">
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="title"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                          <Input
                            id="title"
                            placeholder="Enter Title..."
                            type="text"
                            {...field}
                          />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="grid gap-1">
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="isPublished"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>Is Published</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                          <RadioGroup
                            onValueChange={field.onChange}
                            className="flex flex-col space-y-1"
                            defaultValue={field.value}
                          >
                            <FormItem className="flex items-center space-x-3 space-y-0">
                              <FormControl>
                                <RadioGroupItem value="archived" />
                              </FormControl>
                              <FormLabel className="font-normal">
                                Archive
                              </FormLabel>
                            </FormItem>
                            <FormItem className="flex items-center space-x-3 space-y-0">
                              <FormControl>
                                <RadioGroupItem value="published" />
                              </FormControl>
                              <FormLabel className="font-normal">
                                Publish
                              </FormLabel>
                            </FormItem>
                          </RadioGroup>
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="grid gap-1">
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="content"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormLabel>Content</FormLabel>
                        <FormControl>
                          <Editor {...field} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="grid gap-2">
                  <Label>Upload Image</Label>
                  <SingleImageDropzone
                    onChange={onChange}
                    value={file}
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                  />
                </div>

                <Button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                  Create Post
                </Button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </Form>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateForm;
```

Any help would be appreciated!